# Python lambda not sorting correctly

Tags: python, sorting, csv, lambda

After having several problems solved by  in earlier posts, I now have another error. Sorting by alphabetical order (if sorting == 1) works fine but sorting by Highest Score (if sorting == 2) and Average Score (if sorting == 3) only prints the csv file, not sorting it at all.

```
   print("How do you want this class sorted?")
    print("For alphabetical order (with highest score for each student), Enter 1")
    print("For sorting by highest score (highest to lowest), Enter 2")
    print("For sorting by average score (highest to lowest), Enter 3")
    print ("=============================================")
    sorting = int(input("Choose your sorting method (1,2 or 3):"))
    print ("=============================================")

    file = open("class1.csv", "r").read()

    if sorting == 1:
        print ("First Name, Surname, Score1, Score2, Score3, Highest Score, Average Score")
        for line in sorted(file.split('\n'), key=lambda x: x.split(',')[0]):
            print(line)

    if sorting == 2:
        print ("First Name, Surname, Score1, Score2, Score3, Highest Score, Average Score")
        for line in sorted(file.split('\n'), key=lambda x: x.split(',')[5]):
            print(line)

    if sorting == 3:
        print ("First Name, Surname, Score1, Score2, Score3, Highest Score, Average Score")
        for line in sorted(file.split('\n'), key=lambda x: x.split(',')[6]):
            print(line)
```

The csv file that I am trying to sort is this one:

```
Sarah,Stewart,10,10,10,10,10.0
Harry,Jones,5,5,5,5,5.0
Tom,Smith,1,1,1,1.0
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I assume you're being surprised **lexicographical** sort? `x.split(',')` results in *strings*, not *numbers*...

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to int to actually sort by score, you are sorting strings not ints without casting i.e  `"2" > "10"`:

```
int(x.split(',')[5])
```

You can pass the file object to sorted and use elif, sorting cannot be three numbers at once:

```
with open("class1.csv", "r") as f:
    if sorting == 1:
        print ("First Name, Surname, Score1, Score2, Score3, Highest Score, Average Score")
        for line in sorted(f):
            print(line)
    elif sorting == 2:
        print ("First Name, Surname, Score1, Score2, Score3, Highest Score, Average Score")
        for line in sorted(f, key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[5])):
            print(line)
    elif sorting == 3:
        print ("First Name, Surname, Score1, Score2, Score3, Highest Score, Average Score")
        for line in sorted(f, key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[6])):
            print(line)
```

To sort the file by first name you also just need `sorted(f)`.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I now have an out of range error and I can't tell what's wrong. IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then you have some rows that don't have at least seven elements. You need to check your input. `int(x.split(',')[6]` presumes you have at least seven elements, if you don't then your sort is not going to work as is

Comment: To adhere to PEP20, you'd probably want to define a print_header() that will do the `print ("First Name, Surname, Score1, Score2, Score3, Highest Score, Average Score")`, and call print_header() from the three stanzas.